# Detect 'Apparent' IP on Tor Hidden Service?

Tags: ip, tor

How do Tor Hidden Services detect the 'apparent IP' (exit nodeIP ??) address of visitors?

I've tried this:

```
  for each item in request.servervariables<br/>
  response.write("<br />" & item & "=" & request.servervariables(item))<br/>
  next
```

...and every IP is 127.0.0.1 as it should be at one level.  But I want to provide a hidden service, and like many other sites, I want to reassure users that we cannot detect their real IP address by publishing the apparent IP address.

Any ideas on any code that would give me the ability to publish that 'apparent' IP address?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand you correctly. Do you want to show the users real IP address? This would not be possible due to the design of hidden services.

Answer (score 0):

First, please begin by reading about the architecture of [Hidden Services](https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html.en).   There are six hops between the client and the hidden service.

If you were running a web server as your hidden service, that web server will always receive the ip address in any requests that are passed to it.  You will see those addresses in the apache log, for instance.   If you wish, you could echo those addresses back to the client to provide the assurance you seek.  Tor provides such an IP check service: https://check.torproject.org/, and that isn't even a hidden service.